# redireccionar al descargar pdf en FPDF output

Tags: php, pdf

Mi duda es y espero que me la puedan responder

estoy usando la librería fpdf en el cual hago que al darle clic al botón enviar, me redireccione el PDF y lo descargue, el problema es que al usar el

```
$pdf->Output('D','entradamateriaPrima.pdf');
```

ya no puedo usar en windows location ni el header
¿alguien podria explicarme alguna forma para forzar una descarga y redireccionar en la librería FPDF.

Answer (score 2):

Para descargar y visualizar el archivo debes de usar lo siguiente:

```
$pdf->Output('FI','entradamateriaPrima.pdf');
```

Comment: que significa 'FI'? que es lo que hace ese parametro?

Comment: [Output](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) en este enlace se encuentran todos los parametros que utiliza la funcion Output.

Comment: @Villatoro "F" - Guarda el archivo en el servidor e "I" -  Muestra el archivo en el explorador. Existen otras optiones que se encuentran el la documentacion: http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/output.htm